# React Native i18next Backend not loading json files

Tags: react-native, i18next, react-i18next

Hi I am using i18next with React Native for translations, but am getting the following error when trying to load json files:

```
i18next::backendConnector: lloading namespace translation for language en failed failed loading ./locales/en/translation.json
```

and also

```
i18next::translator: missingKey en translation screens.login.header screens.login.header
```

app/i18n.js

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import Fetch from 'i18next-fetch-backend';

const languageDetector = {
  type: 'languageDetector',
  async: true,
  detect: cb => cb('en'),
  init: () => {},
  cacheUserLanguage: () => {},
};

i18n
.use(Fetch)
.use(languageDetector)
.use(initReactI18next)
.init({
  lng: 'en',
  debug: true,
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false,
    formatSeparator: ',',
  },
  keySeparator: '.',
  whitelist: ['en'],
  nonExplicitWhitelist: true,
  fallbackLng: 'en',
  backend: {
    loadPath: './locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    allowMultiLoading: true,
  },
  react: {
    wait: true,
  },
});

export default i18n;
```

app/locales/en/translation.json

```
{
  "screens": {
    "login": {
      "header": "Login to your your account",
      "loginButton": "Login"
    }
  }
}
```

app/screens/auth/LoginScreen.js

```
{t('screens.login.header')}
```

Has anyone had any success using this library with React Native?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you fix it somehow?

Comment: I fixed it by passing `i18n` as an argument to a function that generates the JSON and then I called the function inside a component, once the languages are gonna be loaded when the component is mount, but not necessarily in a separate file.